# python flask session not updating

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a flask application and i am adding/removing content to the cart via fetch api.  When i try to remove the data nothing gets removed.

```
@cart_bp.route('/cart/action/',methods=['POST'],strict_slashes=False)
def cart():
    fetchapi = request.get_json()
    if fetchapi['action'].lower() == 'add':
        session['cart'].append(fetchapi['item'])
    else:
        session['cart'].remove(fetchapi['item'])
```

After I print the session in the else statement the item has been removed.  However when I refresh the page or navigate to another page.  The cart still contains the item that got removed from the session.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70137349/updated-quantity-not-showing-in-flask-view-for-shopping-cart-session) (solved) too. When you're updating or removing an item from the shopping cart, you need to write that to the session. In my case, it was after I updated the quantity in the `add_product` dictionary (within `cart_products` list of dictionaries):

```
cart_products = [add_product if product['prod_id'] == add_product['prod_id'] else product for product in cart_products]
session["cart"] = cart_products # Without this, my dictionary was updated, but the updated quantity wasn't showing in the cart.
```

I don't know the name of where you'd write this to based on your question as is, but it would be something like:

```
session['cart'].remove(fetchapi['item'])
session["cart"] = fetchapi
```

Or try this after .remove() line: `session.modified = True`