# Updated quantity not showing in Flask view for shopping cart session

Tags: flask

I’m using flask sessions to store a list of dictionaries for a shopping cart in Python. When a product is added to the shopping cart, it gets a dictionary (appended to cart). If the product (‘prod_id’) already exists in the cart, the dictionary gets an updated quantity (updated in cart). This works fine, but I’m having trouble getting my flask cart view to *show* the updated product quantity when the product already exists in the cart. I only need the updated quantity (for the ‘prod_id’) to show in the flask cart view. It's shown when I print/dump the session cart. Fully runnable code with extra print statements. Any help is appreciated.

#### What I've tried

- 1. `session.pop('prod_quantity', None)`
- 2. `session.modified = True`
- **Got** `TypeError: pop expected at most 1 argument, got 2`
- 1. `session.pop('prod_quantity')`
- 2. `session.modified = True`
- **Got** `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

#### Python code

```
def product_exists(product: dict, cart: list):
    added_id = product.get("prod_id")
    in_cart = [existing_prod for existing_prod in cart if existing_prod.get("prod_id") == added_id]

    if in_cart and len(in_cart) > 0:
        return True, in_cart

    return False, None


add_product = {'prod_id': 19, 'prod_name': 'Velociraptor', 'prod_price': 40, 'prod_quantity': 4}
matching_product = [{'prod_id': 19, 'prod_name': 'Velociraptor', 'prod_price': 40, 'prod_quantity': 3}]

cart_products = [{'prod_id': 15, 'prod_name': 'Penguin', 'prod_price': 40, 'prod_quantity': 2}, {'prod_id': 16, 'prod_name': 'Lion', 'prod_price': 20, 'prod_quantity': 4}, {'prod_id': 17, 'prod_name': 'Whale', 'prod_price': 20, 'prod_quantity': 3}, {'prod_id': 18, 'prod_name': 'Cat', 'prod_price': 30, 'prod_quantity': 1}, {'prod_id': 19, 'prod_name': 'Velociraptor', 'prod_price': 40, 'prod_quantity': 7}]

exists, matching_product = product_exists(add_product, cart_products)

if exists: # exists = True
    print(f"Matching product {matching_product}")
    update_quantity = matching_product[0]['prod_quantity'] + add_product['prod_quantity']
    print(f"Updated quantity {update_quantity}")
    add_product.update({'prod_quantity': update_quantity})
    print(f"Product dict with updated quantity {add_product}")
    cart_products = [add_product if product['prod_id'] == add_product['prod_id'] else product for product in cart_products]
    print(f"Product dict in {cart_products}")
    print(cart_products[0]["prod_quantity"])
    
else:
    cart_products.append(add_product)
```

#### Flask view

```
  {% for product in cart_products %}
    <tr> 
      <td>{{ product.prod_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.prod_price }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.prod_quantity }}</td>          
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out all I needed was to write the changes to the session cart:

`session["cart"] = cart_products`